# AppState of other application(s) from my current Application in Tizen?

Tags: native, tizen-native-app

I am writing a test application to test Tizen applications. For this I need to get the AppState of other application(s) from my current Application using below API:

```
AppState Tizen::App::App::GetAppState(void) const
```

Please help me how to get the state ?

Rakar

Answer (score 0):

This method is use to get the state of your current application. I don't see how you could make it to return the state of another application.

To get the current state of your app just do

```
Tizen::App::App::GetInstance()->GetAppState()
```

Maybe you could take a look at the AppControl and see if that helps.